# Laptop doesn't hibernate, when battery is low

Tags: 14.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 and noticed that unlike Windows 7, when the battery gets too low the system just shuts down. In the power settings the hibernate option is greyed out. Is there a way to fix this?

[image: Greyed out Hibernate option]

Comment: Did you [enable hibernation](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html) before trying? Does it work when invoked manually?

Answer (score 0):

answered here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html

Hibernate has not been set by default in this version due to some machines' limitations with hibernation, so first test if it works:

sudo pm-hibernate

if it does, then set it by default by setting:

/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions
ResultActive=yes
```

the first block made my machine hibernate once, but when I restarted it stopped working, the second block makes sure it keeps working